# Castle Windsor Add Components From XML

Tags: xml, initialization, castle-windsor, config

I'm using Castle Windsor in project and currently faced problem with configurations files, there are to many of them, and they are messed up. So I've decided to structurize them.
 I wand to initialize windsor factory with one main xml file, and depending on it's content register remaining components also from xml file.
 I wonder if there is opportunity to register components after the factory is initialized from xml config files.

Smth like this:

```
ComponentFactory.Initialize(Configuration.FromXmlFile("Main.xml"));
var config = ComponentsFactory.Resolve<MainConf>();
foreach(var xml in config.XMLList)
{
    ComponentFactory.RegisterFromXML(xml)
}
```

Comment: which configuration files do you speak of? windsor or NHibernate?

Comment: Windsor, sorry for confuse, I'll edit topic

Answer (score 1):

Following approach can be used:

```xml
<castle>
    <include uri="file://config_part_1.xml" />
    <include uri="file://config_part_2.xml" />
    <include uri="file://SomeConfigurationFolder/config_part_3.xml" />
    <include uri="file://SomeConfigurationFolder/config_part_4.xml" />
</castle>
```

Path is relative to the project folder.

Not sure that it fits all requirements, but it can be used to logically divide castle configurations on set of files.